# iTunesConnect - Application update : setting an availability date in the future

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect, itunes-store

When submitting a new app, you can specify a future date for its availability. For exemple, you can set in March your app to be on the store on Christmas. But I've read in some forums that if your set that availability date in the future for an update, the app disapears from the store.

Is that right ?

If yes, is it possible to send an update for validation and set a future date for its availability, without loosing the current app that is on the store ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can submit an update but ask Apple to hold it after approval until you release it (it's an option in iTunes connect), thus keeping an old version on the App Store and allowing you to choose exactly when the update is released.

Answer (score -2):

yes that is right. but when you submit an update you don't need to specify a future availability update and there is no reason or benefit to do so.

Comment: How can you say that ? You don't know the need. There are reasons and benefits. Think.

Comment: case 1 : You have an app that do things, and for the day of Christmas, you want to release an new version. But, as Apple take days to validate your app, the only way to make sure that your app will be available on Christmas day is to submit it far before that day, especially if Apple asks you to make changes. Case 2 : You want to release the app on a particular day, and you have prepared some promotional events with prints that show that day. Let's say "Hey, the last episode of Angry Birds will be available on 4th July. Don't miss it". It would be bad if it is released earlier or later

Comment: Well I'll give it to you that they are reasons. ;) But they are not benefits imho. To me you have maximum benefit if it's available immediately. SPlitting hairs I know, lol. and thanks for replying too.

Comment: No benefits ? Try launching a "New year day event" on December 1st... Your app will fall into the abims of the Store when reaching the end of the month, with too poor sales. Make it available on the January 1st (or previous day), and it could be on the Top 100 during some days, with many sales. No matter it fall down on the end of the month.